# How to order a dictionary by key and print it into a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary inside another dictionary i.e. I have a dictionary of stock (like a supermarket) that contains dictionaries of the products (like apples) that have their name, amount etc. I need to sort it by key and print it as a table.

Currently I have,

```
stock = load_stock_from_file() 
print("{0} | {1:<35} | {2:^11} | {3:^12} ".format("Ident", "Product", "Price", "Amount"))
print("-" * 6 + "+" + "-"*37+"+"+"-"*13+"+"+"-"*12)

for key in sorted(stock):
print("{name:<35} | {price:^11} | {amount:^12} ".format(**key))
```

This is what I want (below) but I get the error 'TypeError: format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str'

```
Ident | Product                             |   Price   |   Amount
-------+-------------------------------------+-----------+-------------
10000 | Granny Smith Apples Loose           |    0.32 £ |    6 pieces
10001 | Watermelon Fingers 90G              |    0.50 £ |   17 pieces
10002 | Mango And Pineapple Fingers 80G     |    0.50 £ |    2 pieces
10003 | Melon Finger Tray 80G               |    0.50 £ |   10 pieces
10004 | Bananas Loose                       |    0.68 £ |    2.2 kg
10005 | Conference Pears Loose              |    2.00 £ |    1.6 kg
```

My keys are the 10000 numbers and the rest are part of that dictionary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates that your key variable is a str. I guess you need to format the value instead of element. You can try that:

```
for key in sorted(stock):
    print("{name:<35} | {price:^11} | {amount:^12} ".format(**stock[key]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the key (which is a string) to the format method which expects a dictionary in this case because of the double stars. You just need to replace `key` with `stock[key]` in the loop.

There's also the [`format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) string method that you can use here, then you don't need to unpack the dictionary with double stars.

```
for key in sorted(stock):
    print(key, end='   ')
    print("{name:<35} | {price:^11} | {amount:^12} ".format_map(stock[key]))
```

And if you want to sort by price or other values, you can do something like this:

```
for ident, dicti in sorted(stock.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['price']):
    print(ident, end='   ')
    print("{name:<35} | {price:^11} | {amount:^12} ".format_map(dicti))
```